# PUT or PUSH for modifying the existing data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have viewset,

```
class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = s.CompanySerializer   
    queryset = m.Company.objects.all()
```

Which shows the view on `/api/companys`

There is a button for `POST`

[image]

I can add the new data from this form.

Now I want to modify the existing data.

I have basic questions.

1. `PUSH` can modify the data? or `PUT` should be implemented?
2. How `PUT` can be implemented for `ModelViewSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly for updating(modify) data using `PATCH` method, `PUT` for replace data

Description of methods:
https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

To define PUT method you can use follow example:

```
# define url
urlpatterns = [
    url('api/mydata/<id>', views.data_put),
]


# views
@api_view(['PUT'])
def data_put(r, d):
```

Comment: It's patch? not path. I added the     `def patch(self, request, id, format=None):` to CompanyViewSet There appears the patch button Thank you

Comment: @whitebear sorry, typo